# How to read a nginx style config file using shell script

Tags: shell

I am writing a shell script only application. I would like to read file a nginx style config file (like the one below):

```
some_block {
    variable1 value1;
    variable2 value2;

    config_array1 value3 {
        sub_variable1 value1;
        sub_variable2 value2;
    }
}
```

Basically I am trying to make a backup system that would read a similar config file as above. I searched a lot, but didn't find any help on reading any complex config file as above. Any help appreciated.

Comment: I'd be surprised if you found a complete nginx config reader coded in (any) shell language. And, in fact, you most probably only want to support some subset of it anyway. But then you should formulate a bit more explicitly what that subset (a.k.a. *your* cfg. language...) would actually be, and then *also show* how your implementation tries to tackle that, and which specific parts of it you got stuck with. (Then maybe you'll have a chance to get more specific tips than this one.)

For a start, see also e.g.: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2936260/what-language-are-nginx-conf-files

Comment: Look at http://svn.nrubsig.org/svn/people/gisburn/scripts/audiotest.sh . Note var. assigns. like `stk.data[stk.currpos++]=...`. The variable is like a c-lang struct, with as many subdivisions as you need. Note that at the top of this code, it is `#!/usr/bin/ksh93` (most Linux installs just call it `ksh`). You could convert your config into a data-structure thingy and then test variables inside of `case` statements (or if/then/else) (won't be easy!). This may be possible in bash too, but I don't have the time to check it out. maybe others will comment. Are you sure you need to do this? GoodLuck

Answer (score 0):

After going through all the comments here and a bit of Googgling I understand this is not possible straight forward using Shell alone.